# Fetching Toll costs

Tags: here-api

I'm trying to fetch Toll costs data (cost, TollCost groups from the Json response). I'm making the call to https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json with the following parameters

```
alternatives: 0
currency: EUR
rollup: none,total,country
mode: fastest;truck;traffic:disabled
driver_cost: 0
vehicle_cost: 0.46
vehicleCostOnFerry: 0
routeAttributes: none,no,wp,lg,sc
jsonAttributes: 41
maneuvreAttributes: none
linkAttributes: none,sh
legAttributes: none,li
cost_optimize: 1
metricsystem: metric
truckRestrictionPenalty: soft
tollVehicleType: 3
trailerType: 2
trailersCount: 1
vehicleNumberAxles: 2
trailerNumberAxles: 3
hybrid: 0
emissionType: 6
fuelType: diesel
height: 4
length: 16.55
width: 2.55
trailerHeight: 4
vehicleWeight: 16
limitedWeight: 40
weightperaxle: 10
disabledEquipped: 0
passengersCount: 2
tiresCount: 12
commercial: 1
detail: 1
heightAbove1stAxle: 3.5
waypoint0: geo!stopOver!46.8036700000,19.3648579000;;null
waypoint1: geo!stopOver!48.1872046178,14.0647109247;;null
waypoint2: geo!stopOver!48.0690426000,16.3346156000;;null
```

Based on the documentation (https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/dev_guide/topics/calculation-considerations.html), it should be enough to add the tollVehicleType parameter.

For sure I'm missing something, but would be very grateful for any support. Thank you.

Comment: Do you get an error? What is your exact problem? A wrong result, no result, an error?

Comment: @AlexanderDobernig no errors, I do receive the route but no information about the toll costs. In the route node of the Json response I'm receiving: leg, mode, note, summaryByCountry and waypoint nodes. No cost or TollCost nodes.

Comment: Did my answer help you? then please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thank you @AlexanderDobernig, it helped. It offered also an alternative to the service that I'm calling and the approach to "start small" it's indeed a better approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a problem do not use 157 different arguments for an API but only use the minimum required ones to get a result. A minimum working reproduceable example. Then add the additional arguments.
And try to omit all other problematic factors - in this example I just pasted the GET request into the address line of your browser and looked at the output.
So you have no possible interference of any kind by the programming language.

I just did this - registered for HERE API  got the api key  - looked at the API (never did anything with HERE) and 4 minutes later I got the toll cost.. :-)

**Please replace the XXXXXXXXXXX by your own key**

```
https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json?apiKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled
&tollVehicleType=3
&waypoint0=50.10992,8.69030
&waypoint1=50.00658,8.29096
```

and look what it returned AT THE END of 5 pages JSON (lots of JSON before)

```
"cost":{"totalCost":"4.95","currency":"EUR","details":{"driverCost":"0.0","vehicleCost":"0.0",


"tollCost":"4.95","optionalValue":"0.0"}},

"tollCost":{"onError":false}}],"warnings":[{"message":"No vehicle height specified, assuming 380 cm","code":1},{"message":"No vehicle weight specified, assuming 11000 kg","code":1},{"message":"No vehicle total weight specified, assuming 11000 kg","code":1},{"message":"No vehicle height above first axle specified, assuming 380 cm","code":1},{"message":"No vehicle total length specified, assuming 1000 cm","code":1}],"language":"en-us"}}
```

**HERE ARE YOUR TOLL COST :-)**

(NOTE: Keep in mind that there is probably no toll for the given car type and country!
I also got a cost result with a car but it was 0,- because there is no toll for cars in Germany (only trucks) where the example waypoints are located.  )